# Why do I get InvalidUseOfMatchersException when mocking TextView?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, textview, mockito

I have a set of tests to verify some functionality in our Android app.  Part of the code is responsible for putting certain strings into certain TextView's.  So I wanted to create mocked TextView objects to use when testing:

```
public static TextView getMockTextView() {
    TextView view = mock(TextView.class);
    final MutableObject<CharSequence> text = new MutableObject<CharSequence>();
    doAnswer(new Answer() {
        @Override
        public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            text.value = (CharSequence) invocation.getArguments()[0];
            return null;
        }
    }).when(view).setText((CharSequence) any());
    when(view.getText()).thenReturn(text.value);
    return view;
}
```

This works fine with the 2-argument `setText(CharSequence, BufferType)` ... however, most of our code just calls `setText(CharSequence)` so I wanted to capture the string in that case too (as you can see in the above code).

But I get this exception:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:
Invalid use of argument matchers!
2 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
-> at com.me.util.MockViewHelper.getMockTextView(MockViewHelper.java:49)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
//incorrect:
someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
//correct:
someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.
```

I have tried (`CharSequence)any()`, `(CharSequence)anyObject()`, even `anyString()` or `eq("")` just to see if it would work and Mockito still doesn't like me trying to tell it what to do in the 1-argument version of `setText()`.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: I've answered this question, but I'm not 100% sure my answer is correct. If not, could you [edit] this question to clarify which line of your test is the line specified in your answer, line 49?

Answer (score 2):

From [the TextView docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)):

> public final void setText (CharSequence text)

Mockito [can't mock final methods](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/FAQ#what-are-the-limitations-of-mockito); the mock/spy class that Mockito generates is actually a Proxy, but because `setText(CharSequence)` is final the JVM assumes that it knows which implementation to call (TextView's real implementation) and doesn't consult the proxy (Mockito implementation) as a virtual method dispatch would dictate. Presumably the implementation of `setText(CharSequence)` actually calls `setText(CharSequence, BufferType)`, which Mockito assumes is the call you want to mock, and thus it gives you the error message "2 matchers expected, 1 recorded". (The second matcher would be for BufferType.)

You'll need to do one of the following:

- Use [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/), which uses a special classloader to replace Android classes with workable equivalents in tests.
- Use [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock), which also uses a special classloader to rewrite your system under test to delegate to the mocks even when calling final methods (along with a host of other added features).
- Skip using mocks entirely, and use a real object or write a fully-mockable wrapper layer.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  That error message definitely needs some help :)

Comment: This particular case I got working by doing doAnswer(...).when(view).setText((CharSequence) anyVararg(), (BufferType) anyVararg()) ...I guess the anyVararg()'s cover both the 1-argument case and the 2-argument case

Comment: The important part isn't the `anyVararg()`, it's that you're mocking [the non-final two-argument method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.widget.TextView.BufferType)); it'd be better to mock `setText(any(CharSequence.class), any(BufferType.class))`. Be careful, it's still very fragile—you're relying on the assumption that `setText(CharSequence)` calls `setText(CharSequence, BufferType)` and doesn't do much else, in an implementation you don't control.

Comment: yep totally.  (would've saved me 1/2 the day if the exception just told me what the error was :))